# Count from each distinct date, fill in missing dates with zero

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to create an Eloquent query that gets the total number of posts made each distinct day, and if the date is missing, fill it in with a value of zero.

For example, if my table looks like this:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |        date         |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 2015-01-01 01:53:18 |
|  3 | 2015-01-01 02:41:26 |
|  4 | 2015-01-02 12:51:01 |
|  5 | 2015-01-05 08:24:12 |
+----+---------------------+
```

This would output:

```
2015-01-01 : 3
2015-01-02 : 1
2015-01-05 : 1
```

Notice, however, that the days `03-04` are missing. How can I include these dates, but give them the value `0` such that I end up with an output like:

```
2015-01-01 : 3
2015-01-02 : 1
2015-01-03 : 0
2015-01-04 : 0
2015-01-05 : 1
```

Here is my current query:

```
$posts = Post::select(array(
        DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`) as `date`'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*)as `count`')
    ))
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::today()->subWeek())
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
    ->lists('count', 'date');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can there be any assumptions about the range of the dates? For example, you know before hand that the dates will be between 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-31?

Comment: @CrackingTheCode The date is always everything from 7 days ago up until today.

Answer (score 2):

In your SQL results you can generate some "fake-data" in your rows, but u can not generate "fake-rows", exept joining to some "fake(temporary)-table".
In your case ll be much easier to apply some logic around sql-result.

Replace your code with this:

```
$order              = 'DESC';
$endDate            = Carbon::today();
$startDate          = Carbon::today()->subWeek();

$dateInc            = ($order == 'DESC') ? -1 : 1;
$dateCycleHolder    = clone ($dateInc > 0 ? $startDate : $endDate);
$dateCycleEnd       = clone ($dateInc > 0 ? $endDate : $startDate);


$posts = Post::select(array(
    DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`) as `date`'),
    DB::raw('COUNT(*)as `count`')
))
    ->where('created_at', '>', $startDate)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->orderBy('date', $order)
    ->lists('count', 'date');

$postsFinal = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();

while ($dateCycleHolder->ne($dateCycleEnd)) {
    $dateCurr = $dateCycleHolder->format('Y-m-d');
    $postsFinal->put($dateCurr, $posts->get($dateCurr, 0));
    $dateCycleHolder->addDay($dateInc);
}
$dateCurr = $dateCycleHolder->format('Y-m-d');    
$postsFinal->put($dateCurr, $posts->get($dateCurr, 0));

$posts = $postsFinal;
```

its alittle bit flexible, you can change values of this things:

```
$order              = 'DESC';
$endDate            = Carbon::today();
$startDate          = Carbon::today()->subWeek();
```