# Laravel - fill up missing dates and counts from database

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to send number of views for each date based on dates that I get from `$request` . From my query in controller I get data for the charts that looks like this:

```
[{"time":"2016-05-01","count":2},{"time":"2016-05-02","count":3},{"time":"2016-05-03","count":7},{"time":"2016-05-07","count":3}]
```

For that data I need to add missing dates and count of views of `0`. I am trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507251/count-from-each-distinct-date-fill-in-missing-dates-with-zero)  but I just can't seem to implement this solution for my example. This is my method:

```
public function timelines(Request $request){
    $from = $request['from'];
    $to = $request['to'];


    $data = DB::table($request['option'])
                ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as time'), DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date($from).' 00:00:00')
                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date($to).' 00:00:00')
                ->groupBy('time')
                ->get();


    return json_encode($data);
  }
```

Updated code:

```
public function timelines(Request $request){
    $from = $request['from'];
    $to = $request['to'];
    $date = $from;
    $data = [];

    if ($request['option'] == 'time'){
      $data = View::groupBy('time')
               ->orderBy('time', 'ASC')
               ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date($from).' 00:00:00')
               ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date($to).' 00:00:00')
               ->get([
                 DB::raw('Hour(created_at) as time'),
                 DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "count"')
                 ]);
    }
    else {
      while($date <= $to) {
        $formattedDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

        $results = DB::table($request['option'])
                   ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as time'), DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                   ->whereDate('created_at', '=', $formattedDate .' 00:00:00')
                   ->groupBy('time')
                   ->get();

        if(count($results)) {
            $data[] = [
                'time' => $formattedDate,
                'count' => $results[0]->count
            ];
        } else {
            $data[] = [
                'time' => $formattedDate,
                'count' => 0
            ];
        }

        $date = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($formattedDate));
      }
    }

    return json_encode($data);
  }
```

With this I only get count for the first date that I send, for example:

```
[{"time":"2016-03-16","count":0}]
```

Comment: `[{"time":"2016-03-16","count":0}]` -> is this the result you get when you have `$request['option'] == 'time'` or when `$request['option'] != 'time'` ?

Comment: It happens when I have $request['option'] != 'time', but I have come up with a solution already and it works all fine, the way I have set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution worked out for me, I first created an array with all the dates in the time range, with dates set as keys and count values set as 0, and then replaced the values after the query in DB, in the same array with count values from the query:

```
$period = new DatePeriod( new DateTime($from), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($to));
      $dbData = [];

      foreach($period as $date){
          $range[$date->format("Y-m-d")] = 0;
      }

      $data = DB::table($request['option'])
                ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as time'), DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date($from).' 00:00:00')
                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date($to).' 00:00:00')
                ->groupBy('time')
                ->get();

      foreach($data as $val){
        $dbData[$val->time] = $val->count;
      }

      $data = array_replace($range, $dbData);
    }

    return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Hi I want to use same query but there is more values then only count, what updation I need to do ?

Answer (score 3):

@Marco answered it perfectly but there is a little improvement I would like to make. There is no need to call `array_replace` instead of that you can do that in a loop. Like this.

```
$period = new DatePeriod( new DateTime($from), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($to));
$dbData = [];

foreach($period as $date){
    $range[$date->format("Y-m-d")] = 0;
}

$data = DB::table($request['option'])
                ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as time'), DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date($from).' 00:00:00')
                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date($to).' 00:00:00')
                ->groupBy('time')
                ->get();

foreach($data as $val){
    $range[$val->time] = $val->count; //Filling value in the array
}

//$data = array_replace($range, $dbData); <-- No need to do this.

return json_encode($range);
```

Comment: This is a more effective and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answers provide by Maro and Rutvij Kothari is correct and here's a more elegant / simplified version of the same logic.

Instead of using 2 separate for loops, I am using array_map function to do the same.

```
$data = DB::table($request['option'])
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as time'), DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date($from).' 00:00:00')
    ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', date($to).' 00:00:00')
    ->groupBy('time')
    ->get()
    ->keyBy('time');

$range = array_map(function ($e) use ($data) {
    $date = Carbon::parse($e)->format('Y-m-d');
    return empty($data[$date]) ? 0 : $data[$date]->count;
}, CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::parse($from), Carbon::parse($to))->toArray());


return json_encode($range);
```

Also If you want to generate a range such as last 7 days, you use the in-built functions in Carbon

```
CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::now()->subDays(7), Carbon::now());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could loop through all the dates you want to show and count them in a while-loop:

```
public function timelines(Request $request){
    $from = $request['from'];
    $to = $request['to'];
    $date = $from;
    $data = array();

    while($date <= $to) {

        $formattedDate = date('Y-m-d', $date);

        $results = DB::table($request['option'])
                   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                   ->whereDate('created_at', '=', $formattedDate .' 00:00:00')
                   ->groupBy('time')
                   ->get();

        if(count($results)) {
            $data[] = [
                'time' => $formattedDate, 
                'count' => $results[0]->count
            ];
        } else {
            $data[] = [
                'time' => $formattedDate, 
                'count' => 0
            ];
        }

        $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date);
    }

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: why loop the querry when you can do loops on the collection, this is a very poor method

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor Yes, you're right. It is not optimized at all. I tried to give him a quick example that works, to get him going instead of beeing stuck.